# Excel links redirected to login page, but when the link is pasted in the browser, actual page loading

Tags: java, excel, browser, hyperlink, apache-poi

I'm using `apache-poi:3.9` to write the excel file. In one column, I am writing a hyperLink like below

```
final CellStyle hlink_style = wb.createCellStyle();
final Font hlink_font = wb.createFont();
hlink_font.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
hlink_font.setColor(IndexedColors.DARK_BLUE.getIndex());
hlink_style.setFont(hlink_font);
        
// sample value
String value = "<a href=\"https://localhost/user/UserDetailAction.do?userid=213&depid=453\"></a>";
final Document document = Jsoup.parse((String) value);
final String id= document.select("a").first().text();
final String url = document.select("a").first().attr("href");


final Hyperlink hyperlink = wb.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(1);
// Tried with and without encoding
hyperlink.setAddress(URLEncoder.encode(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));
cell.setHyperlink(hyperlink);
cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);
cell.setCellValue(id);
```

It's writing the id as hyperlink in excel(xlsx). But when I click it, it's redirected me to the login page(even when the session is active).

But when I copy the hyperlink from exel and paste it in the browser, it's working fine.

How to fix this?

Comment: Does the hyperlink get opened in the same browser and browser window as the already active session? Your browser probably doesn't send the necessary headers when you click the link in the Excel file - if it isn't opened in the same window that might be the reason why.

Comment: yes. hyperlink opened in same browser which has active session.

Comment: This is not a `apache poi` issue. It is how hyperlinks clicked on Office documents work. The click action tells the operating system: Here is the link, please choose the default browser and open it. It will **not** use any open sessions even if in same browser. And this is good as it is. Else every one, who knows the link, colud open the site without logon, couldn't the one?

Comment: scenario is need to open the expected url if I'm already signed in. otherwise need to redirect to login page. Any fix is there to open the expected url when user already signed in?